# Google Apps Script: Custom function is not returning expected value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In my Apps Script, I need to use the same format of (yesterday's) date in multiple different functions. So I decided to make my own custom `makedate()` function to reliably create this date for me when I needed it. The issue, however, is that it's returning `undefined` instead of my date. Here is my current function:

```
function makeDate(){
  var myDate = new Date();
  var date = (myDate.getDate()-1) + "-" + (myDate.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + myDate.getFullYear();
  Logger.log(date);
  return date
}
```

In the log file, I see that the date is being created in the format I want. However, when I then make another function to test the return value, the log file shows `Made date:` with no date following it, and other uses show that the value is undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem somehow had to do with variable scopes I think actually. I was using this to test code for another script within the project, not realizing that the functions within the scripts are all connected. Once I made sure there was only one instance of every function/global, the problems resolved. Dumb mistake, I know, but it's good to know for any beginners learning Google Apps Scripts so I figured it was worth posting as an answer.

Comment: It's good to post your own answer rather than leaving a question unanswered.  And it is good to try to provide an answer for others searching for an answer to the same problem.  But, it is often very difficult, if not impossible to find a question that is relevant unless the title is descriptive, and the person searching using the same search words.  I often have a very hard time finding posts that I know exist, and I know what the subject is.  You should add the Google spreadsheet tag to your original question.

Comment: Sure, if you think it'll help people who are using Google Sheets. I personally was not but that's good to keep in mind. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0):

your issue is that custom functions return value must not depend on anything other than input parameters. in your case you have none so it will cache the first result and use it for further calls with the same parameters (none).

to fix you must pass the date as a parameter.